# Variable does not work in controller method in asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#

I have a controller named `StudentController`. Here is a method named:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    int val = 12;
    ViewBag.DepID = new SelectList(db.Departments, "ID", "name");
    return View();
}
```

but `val` does not take 12. I don't know why.
`debugger` does not point this line.
when I add watch it shows this **"The name 'val' does not exist in the current context"**.

Comment: Try cleaning your project and rebuilding, and compile in debug mode

Comment: You havn't used val value in your code sample after declaration. what do you want to achieve with this code?

Comment: sometimes it helps when you just close VS and start it again :P

Comment: yes i did not use it. but i have to use it in some other method. i just post a sample. val don't take any value. why?

Answer (score 0):

If your debugger does not step through the first line of your method, you might be debugging a previous version of your code.

Try to clean and rebuild your project. If this does not work, delete the project's bin folder manually. Restarting the IIS (if you are using it) might also help. For this type following in the console:

```
iisreset
```